# Validaciones en MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Como puedo agregar validacion a un  @Html.Textbox en un View Details. este es el codigo.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    @Html.TextBox("Referencia");

    <input value="Referencia" type="submit">


<fieldset>
    <legend>Vidrio</legend>

    <div class="display-label">
         @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Número_Material)
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Número_Material)
    </div>
```

El Model es un Entity Framework Database First.

HomeController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MostrarInfo(FormCollection form)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string referencia = form["Referencia"];
            var item = db.Vidrios.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Referencia == referencia);

            return View(item);
        }
        else {

            return View();

        }
```

Comment: bienvenido/a a SOes, te recomiendo que revises el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio, edita tu pregunta, agrega modelo que estás usando, de la misma manera, añade la validación que estás buscando. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias cosas que verificar. Alguna de ellas, como lo comenta fredyfx, tal vez no se ven en el texto que nos muestras.

Si tu modelo es creado por Entity Framework, muy probablemente venga con el atributo de requerido. Para tu referencia:

```
    [Required]
    public string Referencia { get; set; }
```

Una vez establecido este punto, habrá que comentar que tu @Html.TextBox("Referencia"), aunque esta nombrado como 'Referencia' en realidad no hace referencia a la propiedad de tu modelo/clase. Lo que necesitas hacer, es igual a lo que haces con tu propiedad Número_Material. Entonces, deberías de tener algo así:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Referencia)
```

Por otro lado, para para ejecutar la validación del lado del cliente, necesitas agregar rutinas de javascript. Te recomiendo uses la mas fácil:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Necesito aclarar que @Html.TextBox("Referencia") no hace referencia a la propiedad de tu modelo _al hora de cargar la vista_, pero _si envía su valor_ en caso de que hagas un http post hacia tu control.